# Learning C for CS50 Lab1: Population Growth - Programm runs, but does not calculate anything

Tags: c, error-handling, cs50

I am learning CS50 to start learning programming.

While doing the Lab 1, I tried not to use the CS50 library since it is only available for that course and if I want to be able to programm in the future, i thought I should learn to programm only with the standard available libraries. So that is what I am trying to do the my code

Basically what I want to do is to keep asking the user to input a number until that number is an integer, so that in case the user enters another value that is not an integer the program won't output anything that is not expected. I am not using the "get_int" function that the Cs50 library comes with, which already does this, so that I can learn for myself how to handle this situation.

So I don't know if the "if" statement for the scanf function is correct to check for that. Can anyone explain to me why my code is not running correctly, or maybe give suggest another solution?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int startPop, endPop, numYears,changePop=0;
    // TODO: Prompt for start size
    do
    {
        RepeatStart :
        printf("enter inicial population: ");
       if(scanf("%i",&startPop)!=1)
        {
            goto RepeatStart;
        }

        scanf("%i",&startPop);
    }
    while (startPop<9);

    // TODO: Prompt for end size
    do
    {
    RepeatEnd :
        printf("enter End population: ");
        if(scanf("%i",&startPop)!=1)
        {
            goto RepeatEnd;
        }

       scanf("%i",&endPop);
    }
    while (endPop<9);
    // TODO: Calculate number of years until we reach threshold

    for(numYears=0;changePop<endPop;numYears++)
    {
        changePop=startPop+((startPop/3)-(startPop/4));
    }

    // TODO: Print number of years
    printf("Number of years to reach a population of %i: %i /n",endPop, numYears);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Lesson 1: Programming with copy/paste is a good way to write buggy code... Why does the "end pop" segment overwrite the variable `startPop`? Good try, but coding requires attention to detail.

Comment: You can't use `scanf` for gathering input from the user and validate it, it has not been designed for that. I suggest you assume the user enters only numbers and forget about input validation for the moment. Instead concentrate on the rest of the program. Also you're abusing `goto`.

Comment: Hint: look closely at this: `changePop = startPop+((startPop/3)-(startPop/4));`. How do you think `changePop` will evolve over time? Hint2: printf the total population inside the for loop, just to see what's going on.

Comment: @jdtg2610 – What do you mean by _my code is not running correctly_?

Comment: You call `scanf` twice in your first loop. Whatever you scanned on first call will be overwritten in second call. And it generally doesn't make sense because if you do not parse successfully in one iteration of the loop, you will get the same error in the next iteration because the input will still be in the buffer. Finally, Using `goto` like that should be a no-go. If you jump somewhere down your code, it might make your code more readable. Jumping back up is basically always a bad idea. Use proper loops for this.

Comment: So after correcting my code according to this suggestion, I got the right code. Thanks.

Comment: @Armali the program prompted for the startPop and after entering, it didn't asked for the endPop. Any idea why that might have been?

Comment: @Jabberwocky what do you mean by abusing "goto", do you have some recommendations how/when should one use it?

Comment: @jdtg2610 google _c goto usage_

Comment: @jdtg2610 if you answer your own question (which is perfectly fine), you should add an **answer**, rather than editing the question.

Comment: BTW: `for(numYears = 0; changePop != endPop; numYears++)` there is a huge problem in the end condition of this loop. I let you find out what it is as an exercise. But anyway `changePop=startPop+((startPop/3)-(startPop/4));` is still wrong....

Comment: @jdtg2610 – Your question "_Any idea why that might have been?_" has already been answered by Gerhardh in the first sentence of his wordy comment.

Comment: `scanf( "%d", &startPop )`

Comment: @Jabberwocky thanks for the tip, though, it turns out the code, I thought was correct, entered into an infinite loop when I entered a char as the inicial population, since there was no break for the loop.